# React-icons/all installation issues

Tags: reactjs, git, npm

I am using react as frontend to build a small project
I want to install react-icons/all in my project project but I am getting error that git does not giving excess to install.
It seems to me that I have to provided some access from my git account but I don't know how. can some help me I am new in react

I am trying to install react-icons/all but getting git access error although I can use react-icons only but I want to install react-icons/all

Answer (score 1):

`react-icons/all` is not any packages the actual package is `react-icons`.

Using npm

```bash
npm i react-icons
```

If using yarn

```bash
yarn add react-icons
```

If using pnpm

```bash
pnpm i react-icons
```